# Globals designation is not being recognised in Excel VSTO C#

Tags: excel, vsto, global

```
public CollageAllFunctionsRibbon()
            : base(Globals.Factory.GetRibbonFactory())
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

I get the message that `"Globals"` does not exist in this context